# Why Java Says not equal between two Strings when thay do equal?

Tags: java

Here is the code, this segment just simply compares two Strings, and returns true or false:

```
boolean eq = Fori.commends.get(39).equals(Fori.commends.get(40)); 
if ( eq ){ 
    System.out.println(
    "40 and 41 are match " +  Fori.commends.elementAt(39) + Fori.commends.elementAt(40));}   
else {
    System.out.println("not match "+ "40: " + Fori.commends.elementAt(39));
    System.out.println("not match "+ "41: " + Fori.commends.elementAt(40));
}
```

And the output likes this:

```
eq is false
not match 40: 11111111111111111111111111111111
not match 41: 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Please, format your code. Try to `trim()` your Strings before the equality test.

Comment: there may be none printable characters, spaces, ...

Comment: also, you use get and elementAt. Without more info on your code, these could have different results.

Comment: Does `elementAt(39)` and `get(39)` return the same thing?

Comment: There is a space character at the end of the series of `1` characters on the last line that begins with "not match 41", but not at the end of the "not match 40" line.

Comment: Write a debug method that tells you where the strings differ (at which character) and prints out the characters in question. Maybe there's a difference you can't see.

Comment: Moreover to what Rohit and rgettman commented, do Fori.commends.get() might return non-String objects which have their own equals() method. Please post the signature of the get() method.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I'm a beginner in Java, seems a stupid questions... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
not match 41: 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

have a space in the end. Thats why they don't match each other.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a beginner in Java, sorry for such questions.